# EOFError when executing python scripts that need user input inside emacs

Tags: emacs, python, input, eof

> EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Is what I'm getting when executing this one line script inside emacs in python-mode (by pressing C-c C-c) :

```
print raw_input(">")
```

Is there a way to make emacs interactively ask for user input ?